# Interchanging circuits between laptop batteries?

Tags: laptop

I have 2 3rd-party (OEM) batteries for my laptop (Lenovo X201 Tablet) with the same capacity and I wonder if it is safe to:

1. Open the battery packs.
2. Disconnect the circuit boards from the cells, interchange between the batteries and resolder.

My problem is that one of the batteries seems to work fine, gets charge and works how long it is expected (~3 hours), but the laptop shuts down randomly (sudden power loss) when this battery is attached to the laptop, even if AC is connected. It is the battery's fault because the laptop works fine with the other battery. I read somewhere that these symptoms should come from a badly made circuit board in the battery. I would like to test if the board is faulty.

Comment: General answer: no. If you know what you are doing, maybe. Are the batteries cylindrical or prismatic?

Comment: Cylindrical. I can solder that is not a problem. I suppose that the circuits in my batteries do not have that advanced locking if they are disconnected because they were cheap 3rd party. Anyway, I would drain the batteries to a minimum to be low voltage while interchanging. I assume it would do the process more safe.

Comment: Anecdotally : there are hangups. I did some surgery on a Sony Vaio battery and killed the battery. Apparently disconnecting the cells wiped out everything in the battery's CMOS SRAM - or convinced it a cell had died completely. It refused to charge or discharge at all after that. Rumour has it you can supply standby power from another power source during surgery but details are sketchy and I cannot confirm or deny that it will work.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That's quite a hack! @ kecsap, I said so too when I needed solder legs on a normal coin cell battery. Holy Moly what an explosion that was near to my face with no warnings. Use glasses and stay outside. Also, bro-tip: It's much easier to handle/put out a fire on an empty parking lot than in your kitchen. Don't ask me how I know.

Comment: @winny : would have been quite a hack if it had worked. If you remember the Vaio 505 ... THE laptop of 1998 ... you'll understand wanting to keep it alive. (The cells all had tabs so soldering wasn't dangerous)

Comment: That carbon-chromium-unobtanium sub-700-gram gem?

Comment: If you try it, use a soldering iron with a rated power of 15W or less.